# How to expose kubernetes dashboard to all users within my vpc using a static DNS in AWS EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I want to expose kubernetes dashboard to multiple users who have access to my vpc, i've seen some examples using internal load balancer with external DNS but i just want to know if there are more suggestions.

Comment: It's no different than exposing any other service.

Answer (score 1):

When you install the dashboard, the service is set as `ClusterIP`. To let users from the same VPC access it you need to change the service to `NodePort`.

```
$ kubectl get service kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.0.184.227   <none>        80/TCP          15m
```

To change it you have to edit the service:

```
kubectl edit service kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
```

And change the `.spec.type` from `ClusterIP` to `NodePort`.

Another option is to patch the service with the following command:

```
$ kubectl patch service -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard --patch '{"spec": {"type": "NodePort"}}'
```

After you edit or patch it your service is ready to be acceded as you need.

```
$ kubectl get service kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort   10.0.184.227   <none>        80:30334/TCP   18m
...
```

Now to connect to the dashboard you have to point your browser to http://master-node-ip:nodePort

```
$ kubectl describe service kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
...
NodePort:                 <unset>  30334/TCP
...
```

```
$ kubectl get node -o wide
NAME                                STATUS   ROLES   AGE   VERSION    INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
aks-agentpool-20139558-vmss000000   Ready    agent   16m   v1.15.10   10.240.0.5    <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.15.0-1071-azure   docker://3.0.10+azure
...
```

So based on this example it looks like: `http://10.240.0.5:30334`

And it can be accessed from anyone in the same network as your master node.

```
$ curl http://10.240.0.5:30334
 <!doctype html> <html ng-app="kubernetesDashboard"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title ng-controller="kdTitle as $ctrl" ng-bind="$ctrl.title()"></title> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/kubernetes-logo.png"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/vendor.93db0a0d.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/app.ddd3b5ec.css"> </head> <body ng-controller="kdMain as $ctrl"> <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser.
      Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your
      experience.</p>
    <![endif]--> <kd-login layout="column" layout-fill ng-if="$ctrl.isLoginState()"> </kd-login> <kd-chrome layout="column" layout-fill ng-if="!$ctrl.isLoginState()"> </kd-chrome> <script src="static/vendor.bd425c26.js"></script> <script src="api/appConfig.json"></script> <script src="static/app.91a96542.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

To know more about the different between all Kubernetes services type, check the following links:

[Publishing Services (ServiceTypes)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)
Kubernetes – Service Publishing

Comment: I know i can do it with an on premise cluster but does't really work for an aws EKS cluster ?

Comment: It works fine on top of AKS. I tested and updated my answer with few adjustments.

Comment: can you access it from the browser because i can't

Comment: Nothing is happening or you have an error in your browser?